# Set a Rails route in an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, initialization

I'm building a web app with Ruby on Rails and I want a route to be user-editable. So I though of adding a simple initializer to add the route the user specified, but I don't really know how can I do this. Is there some easy way of doing it? I tried this on `application.rb`:

```
config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
    Rails.logger.info "#{Rails.application.routes.routes.map(&:path)}"
    MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
        get '/droplet' => 'admin#index'
    end
end
```

But that doesn't seems to work. This is what I have in my `routes.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users 

    root :to => 'target_finder#show_page'
    match '*path' => 'target_finder#show_page'

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give us the 10 thousand foot view of what you are trying to do here please, as it stands we can only guess at what is the real question behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making a controller action that takes in the params, tests to see if they match the configured route, and take action from there.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users 

    root :to => 'target_finder#show_page'
    match '*path' => 'test_if_custom#CustomController'

end

class CustomController < ActionController::Base

  def test_if_custom
    if url_for(params) == Rails.application.routes.routes.map(&:path)
      take_custom_action
    else
      take_default_action # Redirects or errors, maybe.
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem, which can define custom routes from any attribute of the user, so you could have a `:url` user attribute and then use that for the route by adding a `slug` index and then putting `extend FriendlyId` and `friendly_id :url, use: :slugged` in the user model.